# Libertinus and \mathcal

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm using the libertinus font in order to match the math to my text (i used linux libertine). I need a `\mathcal{L}` symbol in my text, but i'm only getting a regular `L`. I looked at the [documentation of the font](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/blob/master/documentation/libertinus-testmath.pdf) and compiled the [.tex document](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/blob/master/documentation/libertinus-testmath.tex) myself. I get a different output, however. Here is a passage using `\mathcal{A}` in the uploaded pdf-file:
[image: Image of uploaded pdf]

here is an image of the same passage in the document i compiled myself:
[image: Image of self-compiled document]

As you can see, there is clearly a difference.

I'm confused. I wanted to find a difference in my preamble to the documentation, but even the documentation (using the exact same .tex file) gives me different results. I have no idea how to fix this, i don't know much about font handling.
Note that this could be my only issue, so having a special treatment of `\mathcal{L}` would be fine (though i would love to learn more about the difference here).

Here is a MWE taken from the linked .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,trace}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont[AutoFakeBold]{Libertinus Math}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\BB}{\mathcal{B}}

%    Enclose the argument in vert-bar delimiters:
\newcommand{\envert}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\let\abs=\envert

\begin{document}
    \begin{lem}\label{p0201}
    Let $\A$ be an arrangement. Then
    \[ \chi (\A,t) = \sum_{\BB \subseteq \A}
    (-1)^{\abs{\BB}} t^{\dim T(\BB)}. \]
    \end{lem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not adding the `.tex` file here? I don't like following external links just to fetch some code...

Comment: Sorry, i added a MWE. I took the documentation file an stripped everything not needed.

Comment: I've used your MWE and I get the output you have shown in the first image, i.e. the desired one

Comment: Hm, this is strange. Unfortunately, adding `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` didn't help.

Comment: My suggestion was an error. I confused libertine with libertinus. I've removed my comment

Comment: I get the faulty output. The font on CTAN seems to be defective. But it worked fine after I downloaded the newer version from github https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/blob/master/libertinusmath-regular.otf, copied it in the current folder and loaded it with `\setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular.otf}[Path=./]`,

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Also I loaded the github - version fonts. They work

Comment: Nice, works for me, too. Thank you very much. Feel free to formulate an answer, i will be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font on CTAN seems to be faulty. You need to download the newest version from github https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/blob/master/libertinusmath-regular.otf and either replace your font or move it e.g. to your current folder and load it with

```
  \setmathfont{libertinusmath-regular.otf}[Path=./]
```

Comment: And, if using LuaTeX, you might need to refresh luatex-cache when you replace an existing font file with a newer version.