# Choice of consistent unicode open-type fonts for Phd Thesis in Engineering

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, thesis, opentype, math-fonts

Having written about 60% of my Phd thesis, I gave it to my advisor for review. I used `Pdflatex` and Latin Modern fonts for text and math. For source code listings, I did not change anything in particular and went with the standard `\texttt{}` variant of the font. My focus was to get content in quickly.

Now, my adviser knows a lot more about formatting than me, but rather than using `latex`, he uses `inDesign` and other WYSIWYG tools for final layout and has challenged me to come up with a contemporary look whilst keeping the overall document's gravitas. Having supervised dozens of students, all producing their thesis with computer modern or latin modern, I guess he is just looking for a fresher alternative. I wish to accept the challenge since I have sufficient time before final submission.

My adviser advised me to use Minion Math, along with Minion/Myriad Pro respectively. He strongly suggested me to use OpenType Unicode fonts and warned that I shall face difficulties when it comes to consistent math typefaces.

It looks like both `xelatex` or `lualatex` can handle the basic requirement of using arbitrary system fonts. But my problem is with Minion Math, since it is not free. My adviser said he will pay for it I cannot find an opentype unicode alternative consistent set of text/math/mono fonts.

This puts me in a dilemma. I really wish to use free & open-source fonts for my thesis because of the following reason. My adviser does not use  `latex` and we were using Overleaf to share he document and obtain adviser feedback through its rich text interface, and we both liked this workflow.  With proprietary fonts, maintaining this workflow might be difficult.

The only other complete set of open-type Unicode font family with math support seem to be STIX, XITS, STIX TWO, Tex Gyre Variants that all seem to be Times-like. I absolutely do not want to go with Times-like typeface for my thesis.

I recently came across Libertinus, that seems to provide all variants - serif, sans, mono and math, which seems promising. However, the github repository of this font suggests that things are still under development. How risky is it to go for this typeface? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: There's a free open-type font called `Libertinus` which I like to use (maybe it's what you meant by `Libertinum`). I don't see any "risks" using it. You'll probably end up doing some more manual kerning in math mode, however.

Comment: tex gyre are not all times like Termes is Times, the others are clones of New Century schoolbook,  Bookman, etc  see http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/gust_e-foundry-math_fonts-presentation.pdf   that said, the math font you found should be stable enough (and once you start your document  just keep with that font so stability shouldn't be an issue)  asana math dejavu math are other possibilities

Comment: For the really authentic thesis look, may I humbly suggest this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344272/1090

Comment: Dear both, thank you. Indeed, I meant Libertinus. Here are some of the problems with Libertinus users have reported within the last few days  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350411/libertinus-and-mathcal , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424079/libertinus-math-too-small-math-symbols , https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413404/unhappy-with-automatic-bracket-sizing-using-unicode-math-and-libertinus.  I really do not know anything about manual kerning (or even what kerning means). There are too many equations to do manual tweaking. Any other options?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I assume the typewriter suggestion was written in jest :) ... My university is pretty strict when it comes to being formal and so is my adviser.

Comment: @Krishna For me it basically comes down to adding or removing some horizontal spacing here and there via `\,`, `\!` and so on, nothing too serious. The other problems you refer to seem to have manageable fixes. I'd love to hear about any more ready-to-use open-type unicode-math ready font, however.

Comment: well my thesis was written on a real typewriter:-) Also are you sure that you want to use opentype, the math font choices are not as restricted as you suggested but they are restricted and more experimental than if you use pdftex. If your supervisor is more used to indesign than tex, his advice may not be totally what you want to follow You will get more choice and much more stable math typesetting if you use pdftex, and if the  document is in the latin alphabet then you will not gain so much. If you need non latin then certainly use xetex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I am not a fan of the upright math used as default in asana math. Dejavu math seems really interesting. But the ```unicode-math``` package you co-wrote does not seem to support it? in the documentation, only tex gyre pagella is listed in the supported list of opentype unicode math fonts

Comment: @Krishna unicode-math supports any opentype font with a MATH table (some of the fonts have probably appeared since Will wrote the documentation) but just as fontspec allows any opentype font to be loaded unicode-math allows any opentype math font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for the quick response. If you could help with a summary answer, I shall gladly accept it. Meanwhile, the CTAN package summary here https://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math?lang=en does not mention Dejavu math. This is confusing/misleading to beginners like me who have no idea of what MATH table means. I need dual language in my thesis, with support for a indic language font not supported by babel/polyglossia.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for all clarifications. Would you recommend Deja vu series over Libertinus family (serif for text, sans for headings, mono for code and math for equations) for consistently formatting an engineering PhD thesis? Or should I make this a separate question. ?

Comment: choice of font (and design issues generally) are mostly considered off topic here. Once you choose a design asking how to implement it in tex is on topic. And you don't want to ask me for artistic advice, you've seen my font creation, also drawings: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142834/1090

Comment: I did wonder about the need for indic fonts but didn't want to make assumptions just from a user name, definitely use xetex then.  For answers, I guess you have looked at the fonts far more recently than me, if no one else answers you could self answer just saying what you'd found.

Comment: Thank you David. Much appreciate this help. More than aesthetics, the stability of a font family and consistency with the rest of the document matter more to me. The question right now in my mind is, whether Libertinus, with its seeming state-of-flux issues in github and here on Tex.sx, is as mature as Deja Vu? I absolutely do not want to do any manual tweaking (because I do not know how to). Last thing I want is to use something that works for a while and later in the middle of 6th chapter of this large document. The question is about __relative stability__ of these unicode math families.

Comment: It would really help us if you provided a better sense of what your advisor considers to be a "contemporary look whilst keeping the overall document's gravitas". Some of this may be related to the selection of fonts outside the Computer/Latin Modern font families, but there's a whole lot more to the notion of a "contemporary look" than just changing fonts. Has your advisor maybe given some examples of publications (books?) which, in his opinion, feature both a contemporary look and a sufficient amount of gravitas?

Comment: I’m not an engineer, but something tells me you’ll be interested in the free fonts designed for [INRIA](https://black-foundry.com/blog/inria-serif-and-inria/?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=Fresh%20Fonts).

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this

Comment: These fonts are only serif and sans serif variants. Monospace is absent and crucially, no math glyphs. Please correct me if I am wrong about INRIA fonts

Comment: Right, at least so far, there’s no monospace member to the family. And as a non-engineer, I don’t know how much math you can get out of the family as it now stands.  But since this was made for an institute of numeric research, it may well come in handy, if only for a smaller project than your dissertation.  My comment linking to  Overleaf’s help is about uploading fonts for use in a project; that Minion is a commercial font doesn’t mean that you can’t use it while collaborating through Overleaf.

Comment: I am aware of loading custom fonts using the fontspec and math-Unicode packages. I also understand how overleaf can compile these documents, since overleaf has these fonts properly installed on their servers. Now, I am fairly sure that overleaf will not support commercial fonts due to licensing issues. These fonts are limited for use in a limited number of machines.

Comment: You need to ping me (put @ before my username) to make sure I see your comments.  You’re not limited to fonts installed by Overleaf.  And uploading a font for use in your project isn’t the same as making it available to the whole world.  If you and your advisor have a license, and you’re the only ones collaborating, there should be no problem.

Comment: If you like a particular math font, except for certain symbols, you can substitute another font or stylistic set with the `Range=` option of `\setmathfont`. In particular, XITS and STIX Two have slanted integral symbols by default, but also upright versions that you can select with `\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C}, StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math}`. You could also delete the `StylisticSet=8` option to replace the integral signs in Asana Math with the more slanted versions in XITS Math.

Comment: @Thérèse I guess if the licence is for a certain number of machines (rather than people), uploading it might be a bit fraught. (Even though you're obviously right that it doesn't make it available to anybody else.)

Comment: I have had good experience with the WIP font [Garamond-Math](//github.com/YuanshengZhao/Garamond-Math) for light math. It is in turn based on the superb [EB Garamond](//github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond), and work for latin/greek/cyrillic. [Alegreya /Sans](//huertatipografica.com/en/fonts/alegreya-ht-pro) are also good. In case you need sans serif and typewriter fonts as well I can recommend the [Libertine](//libertine-fonts.org) or [Libertinus](//github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus) superfamilies, and [Iosevka](//github.com/be5invis/Iosevka).

Comment: Adobe has also stepped up its open source font game with Source { [Serif](//github.com/adobe-fonts/source-serif-pro) / [Sans](//github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro) / [Code](//github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro) / Han [Serif](//github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif)/[Sans](//github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans) }. The Han fonts are especially impressive with insane glyph coverage and the same style across glyphs for Simplified/Traditional Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and soon even for Hong Kong. If your supervisor insists on Minion, maybe you could get away with Cochineal.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The situation with fonts is much better than you thought!  I absolutely agree with your advisor that you should use OpenType fonts (and therefore, the `unicode-math` package on either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX).  Any OpenType math font will have more-complete and consistent symbol coverage than any combination of legacy LaTeX packages, but the package also allows you to mix-and-match symbols and alphabets freely.

One thing I’m not entirely clear on is whether you want a monospaced font for code listings or typewriter-letter math symbols.  Any complete OpenType math font contains the latter.

#### OpenType Math Fonts

You can find a list of OpenType math fonts, with samples, [at this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available/425099#425099).  Going over the list there:

- Latin Modern Math is a clone of Computer Modern plus `amssymb`, but has more glyphs.  It is the default when you load `unicode-math`.  If you use this, you’ll get something that looks exactly like the default settings of TeX.
- TeX Gyre Bonum, Pagella, Termes and Schola are clones of the fonts Bookman Old Style, Palatino, Times and Century Schoolbook, respectively.  You said you don’t want Times, but you can have a look at the others.
- TeX Gyre DejaVu Math adds math support to the DejaVu fonts, which are based on Arev, based on Bitstream Vera.  There is also a sans-serif font. The DejaVu project calls this DejaVu Math TeX Gyre.
- Asana Math is based on Palatino, and its symbols resemble those of `mathpazo`, and its successor, `newpxmath`.
- Libertinus Math is based on Linux Libertine and Linux Biolinum.
- GFS Neohellenic has very small serifs, giving it a unique look good for presentations.
- [Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) is a clone of the Euler font by Hermann Zapf, originally created for DEK’s book *Concrete Mathematics*.  This font is incomplete and doesn’t ship with TeX Live.  It does not have nearly as many glyphs as the other fonts on this list.  Therefore, you would need to download it separately, load only the glyphs it supports, and use another font, such as Asana Math or TeX Gyre Pagella, as your fallback font.
- Stix, Stix Two and XITS are all based on the STIX project, which is based on Times.  Since you said you don’t want something that looks like Times, these are out.
- Cambria Math is not free, but it’s included with recent versions of Microsoft Windows and Office, so you might have it on your Windows partition as `cambria_01.ttf` or as a `ttc` file.  You could also get it *gratis* with the PowerPoint 2007 viewer if you’re willing to unpack a few `cab` files.  However, it is the default font for equations in Microsoft Office and looks a lot like Times.
- Minion Math and Lucida are proprietary fonts.

You can find a sample of Asana Math [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asana-Math), all the TeX Gyre fonts [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre-dejavu-math/dejavu-otf-math-2015-poster), and Libertinus [here](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/blob/master/documentation/libertinus-testmath.pdf).

It is also possible to mix-and-match fonts, so as to use the symbols from a math font with the letters from your text font.  One popular recommendation, for example, is Neo Euler for math with Palatino for text.

#### Font Families

Most of these fonts have a matching text font without *Math* in the name.  Asana Math and Neo Euler are good matches for Palatino (and therefore its clone Pagella).

Three of the font families I listed above have matching serif, sans serif and monospace fonts: Latin Modern Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono and Libertinus Mono.  Latin Modern Mono is a clone of Computer Modern Monospace, which you might or might not find attractive and again looks just like the default `cmtt`.  Some of the more obscure variants of Computer Modern, such as Upright Italic, are available through Computer Modern Unicode. There is also a monospace font in the TeX Gyre collection, TeX Gyre Cursor, but it is a clone of Courier and therefore not really a match to any of the TeX Gyre Math fonts.

If you don’t use one of these, there are a large number of free monospace fonts out there, in addition to the ones that ship with your operating system.

You can also use any OpenType monospaced font you want for your typewriter-letter math symbols with a command such as `\setmathfont[range=\mathtt]{Inconsolata}`.

You might or might need an accompanying sans-serif font in your document.  If you want to use sans-serif throughout, you would have to remap a sans-serif family to the `up`, `bfup`, `it` and `bfit` math alphabets, but as an alternative for titles and headers, most of those font families come with small caps.

#### The Script/Calligraphic Quirk

LaTeX packages historically had separate commands for `\mathscr` and `\mathcal`, which displayed different symbols.  The Unicode Consortium decided that these were really just presentation forms and no mathematician used both `\mathcal{I}` and `\mathscr{I}` to mean different things in the same text.  Therefore, it allocated only one range of codepoints for both alpabets.

The `unicode-math` package by default sets up `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` as synonyms for each other, but it supports loading different alphabets into either (as well as `\mathfrac`, `\mathbb`, and so on).  Furthermore, several math fonts contain separate `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` alphabets intended to be used this way.  You can load them with one of the commands `\setmathfont[range={mathcal,mathbfcal},Alternate,Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}` or `\setmathfont[range={mathscr,mathbfscr},StylisticSet=1,Scale=MatchUppercase]{XITS Math}`.  Stix Math or Stix Two Math use the same syntax as XITS Math.

If you don’t actually use `\mathcal` or `\mathbfcal` in your thesis, you can of course completely ignore this.

#### My Recommendation

I personally like Asana Math, with Palatino (or a clone such as TeX Gyre Pagella) as the text font.  However, you say in the comments that you don’t like its upright style.  (I assume you mean the slant of symbols such as the integral; it contains both upright and italic letters, like all the math fonts.)  [Inconsolata](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) is a free monotype font that I think, as a humanist sans, goes well with it.  It ships with TeX Live, but only as a Type 1 font, so you would need to download [the newer version](https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/ofl/inconsolata).  (Either double-click on the file and hit the install button, or on Linux, you can copy it to `~/.fonts` or `/usr/local/share/fonts`.)

The official sans-serif companion font for Palatino is the commercial font Palatino Sans, but Optima, its free clone URW Classico, or [Gillius No2](https://arkandis.tuxfamily.org/docs/Gillius-cat.pdf) (based on Gill Sans) might be a good free alternative, and it ships with TeX Live.

Since you said this is an Engineering thesis, I’ll assume you want to use ISO style, which is the `math-style=ISO` option to `unicode-math`.  To get upright letters for constants as it recommends, you can use, *e.g.*, `\symup{e}`, but `unicode-math` defines `\muppi` for the constant π.

I recommend the `microtype` package to make the right margins and word spacing look neater, with less hyphenation (I contributed a few improvements to it myself).

You also mention the need to support both English and South Asian languages.  You should be able to do something like `\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}` for Indic and `\newfontfamily\malayalamfont[Script=Malayalam]{Free Serif}` for Malayalam.  That should enable Sanskrit in Polyglossia, but for Malayalam, you would need to select `\malayalamfont` manually.  However, the code will still work if Polyglossia adds support for Malayalam later.

#### Legacy Fallback

If you absolutely must use pdflatex, first load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. It wouldn’t hurt to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but that’s now the default.  The packages `tgpagella`, `newpxmath`, `inconsolata` and `classico` would set your main, math, monospace and sans-serif font to a combination I like.  (The only real problem with it is that Palatino might be overused, but at least it will be taken seriously.)  If you want to tweak the math alphabets some more, look at the package options to `newpxmath` and consider a package such as `mathalfa` or `isomath`.

If you need to support PDFLaTeX, you can use the `\iftex` package to wrap the leagacy NFSS preamble and the modern `unicode-math` preamble in conditional blocks.  Then, you’ll use modern features if your TeX engine supports them.

#### PS

I have one other quirk in my papers: Math fonts use wildly different symbols for *Q.E.D.*  I personally like to use the black “tombstone”, introduced by Paul Halmos and used in the 1997 edition of *The Art of Computer Programming* by DEK. The command for this is `\setmathfont[range="220E]{XITS Math}`, and to use it with `amsthm`, `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\ensuremath{\char"220E}}`.

Comment: That is indeed a very comprehensive answer. Thank you very much for the clear, expository information. Just to clarify, I need the monospaced variant for code listings. In this scenario, I think I shall try libertinus serif for text, sans serif for headings, monospaced for code listings and it's math variant for equations. If this doesn't work for my adviser, I shall fall back to Texas Gyre Schola since that's the only one that seems reasonable to my eyes, atleast

Comment: Okay. By the way, does `\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika}` (or another font) work for getting your multilingual text in Polyglossia?

Comment: I shall need both Sanskrit and Malayalam in my dedication section, the latter ofwhich is not  currently on polyglossia

Comment: I don’t know either language myself, unfortunately, but in that case, you can still write `\newfontfamily\malayalamfont[Script=Malayalam]{Free Serif}` in the preamble and then `{\malayalamfont മലയാളം}` in your dedication.

Comment: Your answer alludes to a "TeX Gyre DejaVu Sans Math" font, which I never saw anywhere, and seems to be unheard of by Google. Where did you found ite ? How can it be obtained ?

Comment: @user2903730 Whoops! That’s a font that was at one point announced by the TeX Gyre project, and they still include a sample of it on their webpage, but the font was never released. Unfortunately, no one’s converted its forerunner Arev Math to OpenType and mapping DejaVu Sans to the math alphabets of TeX Gyre Dejavu Math doesn’t work out of the box because the script sizes are wrong. The OpenType math font with the subtlest serifs is currently GFS Neohellenic. I’ve removed the erroneous reference; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You mention that it is possible to use letters from one font, and symbols from another. Could you show an example of how this would be done?

Comment: @tadejsv It’s better to pose a question on the site than to one person, but, here you go: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422854/problems-with-using-numbers-and-italic-greek-of-alegreya-font-in-math-mode/424123#424123

Answer (score 4):

Summarising the comments into an answer:

- Although not as exhaustive as true-type/PS1 fonts, there exist other unicode opentype free families providing the complete set of serif, sans serif, mono and most importantly, math fonts.
- Tex Gyre Deja Vu, Asana Math, Libertinus etc are such examples.
- Libertinus is considered stable for usage in large documents.
- Although the summary on CTAN is a bit outdated, the unicode-math package does indeed support any unicode opentype math family (font with MATH tables)