# When (and why) to use manual kerning for mathematical content?

Tags: math-mode, typography, best-practices, kerning

I recently asked here, a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424474/choice-of-consistent-unicode-open-type-fonts-for-phd-thesis-in-engineering) about the choice of OpenType Unicode fonts for my PhD thesis. After considering the comments and answers to the question, I decided to use `Libertinus` for both text and math.

However, one of the comments to my question keeps nagging my inner self. To paraphrase it, they cautioned me that I shall end up having to do some more manual *kerning* in math mode.

I do not possess an in-depth knowledge about typographic convention and best practices. Inspired by this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space) wherein that user had asked about when should they be using non-breaking space, in the same vein, I would like to seek best practice guidance on the following issue:

**When (and why) do we need manual kerning for math content when using certain fonts**?

Comment: Why? Aesthetics, maybe?

Comment: @OlegLobachev or in addition, it may well be an established typograpic practice, similar to standard conventions for hyphenation, leading and tracking. I am interested in such best practices and how to achieve them in a latex document.